# how to use global variable in drools

Tags: drools

I have a drools file (.drl) which I am using to trigger rules. I have declared a global variable in the same file. However I am unable to use the same.

DRL:

```
global Boolean testValue                              // line 1
System.out.println("Global testValue: "+testValue)    // line 2
```

When I call the rules, I get an error on line 2. The `testValue` is being populated prior to calling.

Any suggestion, or where I am going wrong? I am certain this is not a syntax error.

Comment: into error, what error? Maybe you have to give it a value first. Did you try that?

Comment: Not sure why this is closed. The code is _right there_ (obviously the "1" and "2" are line numbers and not in the code itself.) And it's perfectly answerable by the people who answer in the "Drools" tag. Voting to reopen so it can be answered (if not by me then someone else in the tag.)